# How to use string methods inside FlatList react native

Tags: react-native

I need to use `slice()` method in my FlatList data but when I use it like below it doesn't work.

```
 <FlatList data={userBookings} keyExtractor={item => item.id} renderItem={itemData => (
          
   <Text style={styles.text}>{itemData.item.id.slice(3)}</Text>
.
.
.
   )
  }
/>
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think first mistake is not to use curly brackets for callback data.
2. Secondly you need to specify the first and last index for the `.slice` method

You can find the answer down below.

```
    <FlatList 
         data={userBookings} 
         keyExtractor={item => item.id} 
         renderItem={({itemData,index}) => ( 
              <Text style={styles.text} 
                 {itemData.item.id.slice(0,3)}
              </Text>
         )}
    />
```

Comment: thanks for the help, the first one which remove curly brackets lead to an error but the second one was the answer. I need to specified the last index.

Comment: First one is not leading you to remove the curly brackets. Instead it basically suggests you to use curly brackets. Thanks from me.